# Is it OK to inquire about my application status after a late application submission?

Tags: application, etiquette, internship, deadlines

I recently encountered a situation regarding the submission of my application for a 9-month academic program. I submitted my application after the deadline by 40 minutes and now find myself contemplating whether it would be appropriate to reach out to the program and inquire if my application will still be considered or will be overlooked. I was enthusiastic about this opportunity.

What would be the most professional and appropriate way to approach the program regarding my late application or shouldn't I do it at all?

Comment: There’s never any harm in asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can inquire with a polite mail. Explain that you were 40 minutes late, and ask if you'll be included or not. Their rules may be strict or not.

You don't need to give a reason unless asked.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but, I worry that way I am forcing them to tell me "no" as they might not want to look like they don't take rules seriously. My impression is that they are strict. At the same time, I thought that if I asked them if there is a chance my application will be reviewed while apologizing for this oversight. It might work in my favor.

Comment: Who can say? If you have a need to know, then ask.